# How to make a twisted wrapper/cloth

Tags: mesh

How do I make a twisted wrapper like the following?

[image]

I've tried to twist a plane / a cone, but many faces just go though others.

Comment: Apologies if this is obvious or not relevant, but if it's for a piece of candy, the twists on each end go in opposite directions so it opens when you pull. Yum.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Leander has given a nice solution with *Cloth* physics, here are solutions with modeling only, you can give them *Cloth* physics at the end if you want to make it more realistic.

- A bezier curve to which you give a bevel object and a taper object. If you select the bezier vertices you can twist them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to reset, *N* panel > *Transform* > *Tilt* to type a value.

[image]

- A tube mesh to which you give a *Mesh Deform* modifier. Create a cube that encages it, choose it as the *Mesh Deform* object, create a basic shapekey, then a new one that you twist the way you want (no risk of face intersections with this method).

[image]

- If you give it a *Cloth* physic afterwards (here Leather).

[image]

Answer (score 24):

If you want to use the cloth simulation, you have to assign both ends to bones.

[image: bone influence]

You also have to create the Pinning group for the cloth simulation. At the pinched end, I used only a few vertices for pinning, otherwise the circular structure will remain rigid.

[image: pin group]

Animate the right hand bone twisting.

[image: twisting]

This is the result with a cloth simulation.

[image: cloth simulation]

[image: settings]

Comment: I thought of something like that but I didn't know it would give such a good result. It would be nice to have your cloth settings

Comment: Added some settings.