# twist cloth for messy sheets

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make a few different works where I need twisted messy sheets. I both want to be able to animate them (from a made bed to an unmade type of bed), and transform them to meshes of good closeup quality. I've tried all afternoon with the simply cloth addon, hook modifiers and empties, vortex force fields and collisions but I'm not even close to what I want.

I've found these two posts: [How to twist a cloth?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165903/how-to-twist-a-cloth)

[How to make a twisted wrapper/cloth](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157438/how-to-make-a-twisted-wrapper-cloth)

which are close to what I want. But I've never worked with rigging or bones and do not really understand the explanations or if that is the best way to go? Aiming for something like this but a bit more like a spiral.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)